# Default cursor in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, mouse-cursor

I am changing cursor of a control in `WPF`.

```
btn.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
```

After carrying out an operaton, I want to revert back to the default cursor, I am did not find any `Cursors.Default`, how to get the default cursor ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can override the cursor instead of setting the cursor, like this:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
```

Then when the operation is carried out, you can remove the override by setting it to null, like this:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
```

Comment: any difference(effect, side effect) compared to `btn.Cursor`?

Comment: I had to check my own WPF app and this is exactly what I do when I want to set the cursor back to "default" (arrow)

Answer (score 13):

You are right. There is no `Cursors.Default` static property. But you can always set cursor of a control to `null` and it will restore control's default cursor.

```cs
// ...
btn.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
// whatever... your operation.
btn.Cursor = null;
// now the Cursor is default again.
```

Comment: Works with MVVM, too

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store the current cursor in a variable before changing it to the Wait cursor and then set it to your cursor variable when you want to change it back.